# How can I clear previous values of the combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    lblbrand.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
    strb = lblbrand.Text


    connetionString = "Data Source=HRS\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='E:\My project\forms\1\1\mobile shop management.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
    con = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    con.Open()
    command = "select Model_id from mob where Brand ='" & lblbrand.Text & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(command, con)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.HasRows = True Then
        While rd.Read()
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(rd("Model_id"))
        End While
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: where is the code which tries to clear "previous values" and does that mean selections?

Comment: Always use parameters for your queries to avoid sql injection.  Also, your HasRows check isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
```